# What doctrine2 version for PHP 5.6.30

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I need to deploy Doctrine on php version 5.6.30. It is possible? If so, how should I set dependencies in composer.json?

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/annotations v1.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.5.0].
    - doctrine/annotations v1.5.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for doctrine/cache v1.7.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[v1.7.1].
    - doctrine/cache v1.7.1 requires php ~7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for doctrine/collections v1.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/collections[v1.5.0].
    - doctrine/collections v1.5.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for doctrine/common v2.8.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[v2.8.1].
    - doctrine/common v2.8.1 requires php ~7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for doctrine/dbal v2.6.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[v2.6.2].
    - doctrine/dbal v2.6.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for twig/twig v2.4.3 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.4.3].
    - twig/twig v2.4.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Comment: Thai should handle composer for you: try `composer require doctrine/orm`. Without any dependency in `composer.json`

Comment: Delete composer.lock and run composer install help.

Comment: Awesome! I've put our comments into propper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing any Doctrine dependencies from `composer.json`, delete `composer.lock` and call composer via CLI:

```
composer require doctrine/orm
```

The composer itself will pick best dependencies to match your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

Delete composer.lock and run composer install help.